# Best way to have two versions of a dependency per application part using Unity?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I am using Unity and MVC5 .NET 4.6

- I have a data service.
- It depends on a repository.
- Which in turn depends on a connection.

The connection requires a username/token to make a connection OR a user/application guid to make a connection to a data source.

Both MVC controllers and Web API use the data service, but the data service should not care about how it is being used.

- When I used an MVC controller the username and a token is is in the
  claim.
- When a connected application uses the API it must pass in the
  user GUID and application GUI.

When I inject the data service to the controller Unity news up all the dependencies, data service with a repository injected and the repository the connection injected.

The question is what is the best pattern for getting the variables for the user to the connection from the current controller?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure two different containers, one for MVC and one for Web API. Or, if you have a service that needs to be shared between MVC and Web API (e.g. a singleton service), you can create two Child Containers (call `container.CreateChildContainer()`) of the container you already have and only register the connection in the Child Containers. You can then make a distinction between which connection is used for MVC and for Web API.